# I can't write in my inputs text using Reactjs and TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, forms, input

I think I'm doing things right as far as my code is concerned. In this moment, i can't write in the inputs. Someone knows what happen? Below I attach my code:

```
const Login: SFC<LoginProps> = ({ history }) => {
    const alertContext = useContext(AlertContext);
    const { alert, showAlert } = alertContext;
    const authContext = useContext(AuthContext);
    const { message, auth, logIn } = authContext;
    useEffect(() => {
        if (auth) {
            history.push('/techs');
        }
        if (message) {
            showAlert(message.msg, message.category);
        }
    }, [message, auth, history]);
    const [user, saveUser] = useState({
        email: '',
        password: ''
    });
    const { email, password } = user;
    const onChange = (e: any) => {
        saveUser({
            ...user,
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        })
    }
    const onSubmit = (e: any) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (email.trim() === '' || password.trim() === '') {
            showAlert('All fields are required', 'alert-error');
        }
        logIn({ email, password });
    }

    return (
        <>
            ...
                    <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                        <input type="text" ... value={email} onChange={onChange} />
                        <input type="password" ... value={password} onChange={onChange} />
                        <input type="submit" className="fadeIn third" value="Log In" />
                    </form>
            ...
        </>
    );
}

export default Login;
```

And this is what the component looks like:

[image]

Comment: do you have the names in your inputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must be because your onChange isn't working the way you expect it to so the value of email is never changing.

I can see two possible issues.

1. in your onChange, why are you saving e.target.value to e.target.name? Unless the name prop is in your code but you left it out as part of the ellipsis. In which case, it's probably number 2:
2. Try having email and password as individual pieces of state (strings created with individual calls to useState). This will require two change handlers (or a more creative single handler, and if you indeed have a name prop then your current handler might already work. If the name prop is working).  You're never using the user object anyway, and it's possible/likely that this is actually your Actual problem (not just a best practice).